# How to bind data from component nested to parent component in form?

Tags: angular

I have a web application with `Angular 4` and `Angular Material`, my application will be very simple, it will have a form in which it receives 2 date parameters, but these date parameters each I have in a component of my own, my problem is that send the `form` I do not receive a data in `onSubmit`, is it okay as I am doing or my structure is very bad?

```
.
├── app-routing.module.ts
├── app.component.css
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.spec.ts
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── dashboard
│   ├── dashboard.component.css
│   ├── dashboard.component.html
│   ├── dashboard.component.spec.ts
│   └── dashboard.component.ts
├── data-table
│   ├── data-table.component.css
│   ├── data-table.component.html
│   ├── data-table.component.spec.ts
│   └── data-table.component.ts
├── filter-time
│   ├── filter
│   │   ├── filter.component.css
│   │   ├── filter.component.html
│   │   ├── filter.component.spec.ts
│   │   └── filter.component.ts
│   ├── filter-time.component.css
│   ├── filter-time.component.html
│   ├── filter-time.component.spec.ts
│   └── filter-time.component.ts
└── shared
    ├── dashboard.service.spec.ts
    └── dashboard.service.ts
```

This is my form in html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
    <md-card>
      <app-filter-time>Loading filter time...</app-filter-time>
      <button md-raised-button>Buscar</button>
    </md-card>
</form>
```

In my structure app is root component, the call to `DashboardComponent` and this show a filter-time component and a button, in the `filter-time` there is a `datePicker` into `filter component` to receive date, but when I put the button, not working, but I think I need other structure to work my data.

**MY PROBLEM**
I can't bind data from datePicker to function onSubmit.

Comment: your structure looks fine to me, the problem looks like it is because `ngModel` or `formControlName` are missing from the form you have posted, which you would expect (and need) from a [template driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or a [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: I read your post and can't understand the question. I see close to 50 lines of folder structure, that doesn't really tell me anything. Try and hit the problem in the first sentence. If you can't do that put most important stuff in bold using double asterisk at either end...